# VMWare error with Kali Linux

Tags: windows, kali-linux, shutdown, reboot, vmware-workstation

I have installed Kali Linux 2017.1 x64 in VMware Workstation Pro 12.5.6 along with the VMware tools (Is that the culprit?). My host is Windows 10 Creators Update 1703 build 15063.322 I have been facing this error from the beginning while shutting down. Could someone tell me why this happens and how to solve it?

[image: Error 1 0f 2]

[image: Error 2 of 2]

P.S.: I have seen a similar , but not same question, but it was closed and that solution didn't work for me. So please don't quote that.

Between, I just got this new error after a 'clock watchdog timeout' BSOD on host but am unable to post because I don't have more than 10 reputation..

Comment: This is a systemd issue. Have a look at this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310737/64248.

Comment: This might be also for you: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?32498-Delay-90-seconds-on-shutdown. Note that to find this required only a few seconds at Google (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=a+stop+job+is+running+for+user+manager), so that might be one reason for the downvotes: obvious lack of prior research.

Comment: @countermode Thanks for the quick reply. And, by the way, I have already gone through these links. I think my issue is related to the DHCP lease as far as I could understand from the log.

Comment: @countermode I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I searched a lot and couldn't find the answer. But that didn't stop me from testing myself.

Solution: DO NOT tick mark 'Accelerate 3D Graphics'. Let it be disabled for Kali Linux.

[image: DO NOT tick mark 'Accelerate 3D Graphics']