# Why I'm giving message `A start job is running for raise network interfaces` at boot after disabling predictable network interfaces names?

Tags: debian, systemd, network-interface

I disabled predictable network interfaces names by changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line in /etc/default/grub from:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pci=nomsi"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pci=nomsi net.ifnames=0"
```

on a fresh installation of Debian GNU/Linux testing system with installed proprietary NVIDIA drivers. I did it because my external USB Wi-Fi card didn't work with systemd interfaces names.

After disabling predictable network interfaces names I'm giving following message at boot:

> A start job is running for raise network interfaces (2 minutes of 5
>   mins 1 sec)

and system boots long.

My `/etc/network/intefaces` file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Why am I giving this message at boot? How can I avoid long booting of my system?

Comment: A background question on the jargon: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310737/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved by changing file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` from:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: This worked for me in Debian 9.1

Answer (score 6):

Disable the service that waits to start the network interfaces.

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

And to enable:

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Alternatively you can reduce the amount of time that it waits to start the job.

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service 

TimeoutStartSec=5min ##Change parameter, should be at the end of the page.
```

Comment: Be aware that this generally fights the *symptom* of an interface not coming online. It may not solve the underlying problem.